# prestashop 1.6.1.8 Table 'prestashop.ps_cms_block' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

please help , the accueil work fine but whene i click on categorie or product , this error show on,

[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

```
Table '........_prestashop.ps_cms_block' doesn't exist

SELECT bc.`id_cms_block`, bc.`id_cms_category`, bc.`display_store`, ccl.`link_rewrite`, ccl.`name` category_name, bcl.`name` block_name
            FROM `ps_cms_block` bc
            LEFT JOIN `ps_cms_block_shop` bcs
            ON (bcs.id_cms_block = bc.id_cms_block)
            INNER JOIN `ps_cms_category_lang` ccl
            ON (bc.`id_cms_category` = ccl.`id_cms_category`)
            INNER JOIN `ps_cms_block_lang` bcl
            ON (bc.`id_cms_block` = bcl.`id_cms_block`)
            WHERE bc.`location` = 0
            AND ccl.`id_lang` = 1
            AND bcl.`id_lang` = 1
            AND bcs.id_shop = 1 AND ccl.`id_shop` = 1
            ORDER BY `position`

at line 791 in file classes/db/Db.php

  if ($sql) {
791.                 throw new     PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
792.             }


DbCore->displayError - [line 425 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 643 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->executeS - [line 360 - modules/blockcms/BlockCMSModel.php] - [1 Arguments]
BlockCMSModel::getCMSCategoriesByLocation - [line 581 - modules/blockcms/BlockCMSModel.php] - [2 Arguments]
BlockCMSModel::getCMSTitles - [line 802 - modules/blockcms/blockcms.php] - [1 Arguments]
BlockCms->displayBlockCMS - [line 841 - modules/blockcms/blockcms.php] - [1 Arguments]
BlockCms->hookLeftColumn - [line 587 - classes/Hook.php] - [1 Arguments]
HookCore::coreCallHook - [line 544 - classes/Hook.php] - [3 Arguments]
HookCore::exec - [line 581 - classes/controller/FrontController.php] - [1 Arguments]
FrontControllerCore->initContent - [line 129 - controllers/front/CategoryController.php]
CategoryControllerCore->initContent - [line 189 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 28 - index.php]
```

thank you so much for help

Comment: Always try and review your question before posting, especially code formatting.

Comment: what ? my english is not so good ,

Comment: thanks i get this ,

Comment: It sounds like your db schema is out of date.  You might have better luck posting in one of their [forums](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/?k=880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024)

Answer (score 0):

There is a table 'cms_block' in default installation of PrestaShop. It seems that this table is not existing in your PrestaShop database.

Try executing the following queries in your database and it should fix your issue.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_cms_block` (
`id_cms_block` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_cms_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_store` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `ps_cms_block` (`id_cms_block`, `id_cms_category`, `location`, `position`, `display_store`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

ALTER TABLE `ps_cms_block`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_cms_block`);

ALTER TABLE `ps_cms_block`
MODIFY `id_cms_block` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Comment: but the shop work well in the local ; and whene i migrate to web the problem show

Comment: i did exuct your code , the table is added but the same problem show on

Comment: sorry , a new problem show ;;; thank you for helping ,,

Comment: (( Table 'cecidxeu_prestashop.ps_cms_block_shop' doesn't exist )) whene i check the table is exist

Comment: Table 'cecidxeu_prestashop.ps_cms_block_shop' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate your shop the DB import didn't finish completly. Check that `sql` file has all tables (from `access` to `zone`). Then delete all tables from your online server and run de SQL script again. That's all you need to do.

Good luck

Comment: thank you for help , i did it dont work , the DB is all well from access to zone_shop